# Direct sums, Span,Union,Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: K and T are sub-sets of Linear Space V

and also $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ is a direct sum, and $Sp(K \cup T) = Sp(K) \oplus Sp(T)$

I need to do show that $ K \cup T$ isn't necessary independent.

I said that: $ V = R^2, $ $K = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ ,$ T = \{(1,1)\}$

From here I can say that $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ is a direct sum because their sum is V and their intersection is zero.
and also, $Sp(K \cup T) = Sp(K) \oplus Sp(T)$ because their sum is $Sp(K \cup T)$ and their intersection is zero.

From here we see that $K \cup T = \{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ but $(1,1)$ is dependent by $(1,0) $and $(0,1)$ which makes it not necessary independent.

The question is, did I prove it right, maybe my sub-sets are wrong and I need other ones? Or just adding $(0,0)$ to K and T is enough to show that there isn't necessary independence(which is a another solution)?

Comment: Yes jut add $(0,0)$ to $K$ or $T$ is enough.

Comment: In your example $$(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)\in Sp(T)\cap Sp(K)$$ so the sum cannot be direct...

Comment: @user63181, that's not correct, because the sum in the OP is not direct!

Comment: What do you mean Ludolila? Can you give an example that if you (0,0) to K or T it will not show a direct sum?

Answer (score 1):

Simple counterexample

$$K=\{ (1,0)\,,\,(2,0)\}\;\;,\;\;T=\{(0,1)\}$$